# Axis label missing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a 3D plot but I am having trouble with the z-axis label. It simply doesn't appear in the graph. How do I amend this? The code is as follows

```
# Gamma vs Current step 2
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = np.arange(0.1,5.1,0.1)
gamma = np.arange(0.1,5.1,0.1)
sigmaz_hgam = np.array([.009998,.03988,.08878,.15403
,.230769,.312854,.394358,.4708311,.539697879,.6,.6518698
,.696033486,.73345752165,.7651390123,.792,.814845635
,.8343567,.851098499,.865535727,.8780487,.8889486,.89848986
,.906881,.914295,.9208731,.9267338,.93197569,.93668129
,.9409202379,.94475138,.951383,.9542629,.956895,.959309
,.961526,.9635675,.96545144,.9671934,.968807,.97030539
,.9716983,.972995,.974206,.975337,.97639567,.977387,.978318
,.97919266,.98,.9807902])

mu = 1
sigmaz_hgam = mu*sigmaz_hgam
# creates an empty list for current values to be stored in
J1 = []

for i in range(sigmaz_hgam.size):
    expec_sz = sigmaz_hgam[i]
    J = 4*gamma[i]*(mu-expec_sz)
    J1.append(J.real)
    #print(J)
```

This part of the code is what is used to graph out which is where the problem lies

```
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = h
y = gamma
z = J1

ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Dephasing Model')
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel('h', fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('$\gamma$')
ax.yaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 3.0
for t in ax.zaxis.get_major_ticks(): t.label.set_fontsize(10)
# disable auto rotation
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False) 
ax.set_zlabel('J', fontsize=10, rotation = 0)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my version of Matplotlib (2.0.2), on a Mac, I see the label (which is there – most of it is just being cropped out of the image in your case).
You could try to reduce the padding between the ticks and the label:

```
ax.zaxis.labelpad = 0
```